# Append div to textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to programmatically add a div after a text area in a form. The div contains a simple counter to indicate the amount of characters the user has left to use while typing in the textarea. Here is the javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ors = {
            desc: {
                maxlen: 5000,
                curlen: 0
            }
        }
        $('#txtDesc').ready(function () {
            $(this).after('<div><span id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '_counter">' + $('#txtDesc').data('maxlen') + '</span> characters remaining</div>');
        }).on('keyup', function () {
            $.ors.desc.curlen = $(this).val().length;
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_counter').html($.ors.desc.maxlen - $.ors.desc.curlen);
        });
    });
```

(Note: I understand the use of $.ors.desc.maxlen in the javascript and then using the data-maxlen in the textarea is redundant, it is still in development though so that's why I've included both. Ultimately there will be other functions going on that require the $.ors object information.)

The HTML for the textarea is simple:

```
        <textarea name="txtDesc" id="txtDesc" tabindex="2" data-maxlen="5000"></textarea>
```

The problem is if I run it as above I get the following error:

"Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined or null reference"

I changed the call to the folllowing:

```
        $('#txtDesc').after('<div><span id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '_counter">' + $(this).data('maxlen') + '</span> characters remaining</div>').on('keyup', function () {
            $.ors.desc.curlen = $(this).val().length;
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_counter').html($.ors.desc.maxlen - $.ors.desc.curlen);
        });
```

but I get undefined as the value instead of 5000. Nothing is working which indicates the $(this) is not working as I expect.

If I change the Javascript to the following it works fine, but then it's locked down to a specific textarea and I can't use it as a function:

```
        $('#txtDesc').after('<div><span id="txtDesc_counter">' + $('#txtDesc').data('maxlen') + '</span> characters remaining</div>').on('keyup', function () {
            $.ors.desc.curlen = $(this).val().length;
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_counter').html($.ors.desc.maxlen - $.ors.desc.curlen);
        });
```

Anyone have an idea what I am missing?

Comment: Try using insertAfter ()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S24Vr/

```
<textarea>Sample</textarea>

jQuery ("<div><p>I am a p inside div</p></div>").    insertAfter ("textarea");
```

To make it usable as a function,

```
<textarea onclick="sample ()">Sample</textarea>


sample = function () {
jQuery ("<div><p>I am a p inside div</p></div>").    insertAfter ("textarea");
}
```

And I don't understand what exactly you are missing.

I updated the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S24Vr/

Comment: It works by itself, but the moment I try to use it within a function it errors out: 

$('#test').ready(function(){
    $("<div><p>I am a p inside div5</p></div>").insertAfter($(this));
});

$(this) has no value and I need it to so I can ultimately use this as function/plugin

Comment: To use it as a plugin, u can create a function as $.fn.functionName ();

So that you can access them like $ (element).functionName ();

Comment: I am trying that but the basic functionality isn't working...heheh

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/S24Vr/2/

HTML:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('textarea')
    .after('<div class="counter"></div>')
    .keyup(function () {
        $('.counter').html($(this).val().length + ' chars typed')
    });
```

Comment: This works, until you change the div to an id that is like the corresponding textarea (ie, $(this).attr('id') + '_counter'). As soon as I do this and try to change the count by using $('#'
 + $(this).attr('id') + _counter'), it no longer works.

Comment: Not sure why will you need this but what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/S24Vr/4/

Comment: There will be multiple textareas on the page using this, I want to update the corresponding span with that textareas info.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your code you could do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/9PY8T/2/

```
 <textarea name="txtDesc" id="txtDesc" tabindex="2" data-maxlen="5000"></textarea>

    $.ors = {
         desc: {
             maxlen: 5000,
             curlen: 0
         }
     }

    $('textarea').

         after('<div id="infos"><span id="counter">' +              
         $('textarea').data('maxlen') + '</span> characters remaining</div>').

         keyup( function() {
             $("#infos").show();    
             $.ors.desc.curlen = $(this).val().length;
             $('#counter').html($.ors.desc.maxlen-$.ors.desc.curlen);
    });
```